Unknown word error only on my computer in index.html file
Every time I type something into vscode I get this error that says "Unknown word (CssSyntaxError)stylelint(CssSyntaxError)" I know it's not my code because this only happens on my computer. I am a beginner and I don't know enough about programming to fix it myself.
this is my code:
``





    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>hello</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum cumque nisi non, a repellendus reprehenderit doloremque tempora nihil rerum ex corporis laborum. Veritatis nam iusto quam nemo perferendis atque animi?</p>
     <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>`

`
I uninstalled and reinstalled vscode, deleted extensions, and looked for errors in my code but it's still there.

Did you reinstall any extensions after reinstalling VSCode?

Are you certain there are not appdata type folders that are persistent? Did you follow their uninstall directions to make sure you get all dependency folders that may be hidden, etc?

https://github.com/stylelint/vscode-stylelint/issues/397

That's your only code? Where is the CSS or JS?

duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/78357415/11107541 (I wrote an answer post there), which unfortunately got auto-deleted by the system.
